# Passing List by ref when IList by ref is the method signature

Tags: c#, list, ilist

I am having trouble with the code below.  I want my method to take an IList, not a List   But am I misguided?

Here is my method:

```
public void DoFoo( ref IList<Foo> thingy) {}
```

Here is the declaration and call:

```
var foo = new List<Foo>();
DoFoo( ref foo)
```

Why will this not compile?  foo definitely implements IList  If is because the compile will have to cast from List to IList ?

Comment: Why do you have a `ref` there in the first place?

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx. But Lasse is right; this code is almost certainly wrong. If you want to pass a list, pass a *reference to a list*, not *a reference to a variable of type list*. The former is `IList<T>`, the latter is `ref IList<T>`; they are very different.

Comment: The normal resolution to this problem is to instead use `public IList<Foo> DoFoo( IList<Foo> thingy) {}` and then use `IList<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>();foo = DoFoo(foo);`.  Still ugly, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type inference gets in the way here. The `var` is equivalent to declaring a `List` directly but you want an `IList`. You'll have to write the expected type explicitly in your declaration.

```
IList<foo> foo = new List<Foo>();
DoFoo( ref foo)
```

Comment: or `var foo = new List<Foo>() as IList<Foo>;`

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't compile is that the `ref` allows the method to do this:

```
public void DoFoo( ref IList<Foo> thingy)
{
    thingy = new Foo[10];
}
```

Arrays implement `IList<T>`, but they're not `List<T>`, and that's why the compiler refuses to compile the code.

You have a parameter that refers to a variable of a specific type, in this case `List<Foo>`, and you can't stuff other types of collections in there, unless they inherit from `List<Foo>`.

There is *one* way to circumvent this, just copy the list to a variable of the right type, but you also need to decide what happens if the method *actually* replaces the contents of that variable.

In other words, you can do this:

```
IList<Foo> il = foo;
DoFoo(ref il);
// what if il is a new reference here now?
```

---

As already mentioned in another answer, objects (and thus lists in this case) are already references. Are you *sure* you need the `ref` in the first place? Let me clarify. Objects in .NET are reference types, which means you pass a reference to the object. Using a `ref` parameter allows you to pass a parameter *by reference*, which is different.

Passing *a* reference allows the method to access the same object as the outside world. Passing *by* reference allows the method to access the *variable* in the outside world.

Comment: As it was said on the other answer, passing by reference and passing a reference type by value is not the same. Default behavior is to pass by value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx

Comment: I know that. Which is why I answered the question asked, but I also wonder what the purpose of the `ref` is as well.

Comment: I figured you would know, but I'm clarifying because of your "objects (and thus lists in this case) are already passed by reference" line.

Comment: Ah, see what you mean, rewriting that passage now.